# Does MarkLogic Fully Support XML Schema 1.1?

Tags: xsd, marklogic

Specifically, multiple substitution groups and XPath asserts in complexTypes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, in the current version we do not support Schema 1.1. 
If you have a use case please post to the marklogic general development group for consideration. Thanks.
http://developer.marklogic.com/discuss

-David