# Support for XML 1.1 in Marklogic

Tags: marklogic

Does Marklogic support XML 1.1 or at least can I use control characters in `xquery version "1.0-ml";`?

From what I see in general XQuery 1.0 is tight to XML 1.0, and in XML 1.0 there is no way to represent control characters (and escaping of them is undefined).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer : [Does MarkLogic Fully Support XML Schema 1.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173016/does-marklogic-fully-support-xml-schema-1-1)

I have read the Marklogic document and have't find any useful info to show MarkLogic 9 support XML 1.1